# Circular reference in states of the Bellman equation

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, puzzles-games

I want to formulate a game of darts as a dynamic program. The goal is to minimize the number of darts thrown while reaching checkout. A dart player has a score *s*. If his score is *s = `2`*, there is only a single legal / possible move.

- He can checkout by throwing at `D1`
- Every other action is not legal and results in a so-called bust and
  the score remains the same, *s = `2`*

The above can be formulated as:

[image]

where *z* represents the outcome on the dartboard

```
z ∈ {S1, S2, S3, ..., D1, D2, D3, ..., T1, T2, T3, SB, DB}
```

The corresponding numerical scores are *h*. So if *z=`T20`*, *h=`60`*

Now the Bellman equation for this DP satisfies:

[image]

Where *V(s)* is the value function when the score is equal to *s*. In addition, *mu* is the aiming location on the dartboard. The reward of each action is equal to `1` (because one dart is thrown). In addition, we have *p*, the probabilities of reaching *s_i+1* when aiming at *mu*, and the corresponding value function of *s_i+1*. The terminal condition *V(0)* is equal to `0`. All of the above can be found op page 13 [here](http://The%20formula%20can%20be%20found%20on%20page%2013%20of%20arxiv.org/pdf/2011.11031.pdf)

So, inserting all for *s = `2`*, excluding the illegal moves, leads to the following:

```
V(2) = min{1 + (V(0) * p(D1;mu))
```

Lets assume there are two possible values for *mu*, namely the center of `D1` and the center of `D19`, which is on the opposite of the dartboard. Logically

```
p(z=D1, mu=center D1) > p(z=D1, mucenter D19)
```

However, *V(0) = `0`*, so

```
p(z=D1, mu=center D1) * V(0) =  p(z=D1, mu=center D19) * V(0) =  0
```

So, if we want to minimize the Bellman curve, there is no optimal solution. Both options lead to the same result, *V(2) = `1`*. However, logical reasoning would suggest aiming for *mu = center D1* is the optimal / desired solution. What am I doing wrong here?

So, I thought maybe I should add the illegal moves into the Bellman equation. This would look as follows:

```
V(2) = min{1 + sum((V(0) * p(D1;mu)) + (V(2) * p(S1;mu)) + (V(2) * p(S2;mu)) + ... + (V(2) * p(T19;mu)) + (V(2) * p(T20;mu)))
```

However, now there is a circular reference for all the illegal moves. How should this be addressed? Should the illegal moves be added? Please help me explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you define all the symbols you're using? $f$, $h$, $z$, $p$, $V$...

Comment: `z` is {S1, S2, S3, ..., D1, D2, D3, ..., T18, T19, T20}.
`h` is the numerical score of z. For example `h`(T20) = 60.
`p` is the probability of throwing `z` when aiming for `mu`.
`V` is the value function.
`f` is the formula that subtracts `h` from `s`.
`s` is the score {0, 1, ..., 501}.

Comment: Can you edit the question and incorporate this to it? It would be easier to read. The meaning of $V$ is still not clear for me, what does it represent physically?

Comment: done. `V` is the value function and represents the value of each score / state

Comment: From what I understand, `V` is the expected number of darts thrown. In this case, the recursive formula looks wrong to me. Can you justify it? Maybe it would be easier with $S(v)$ the expected score using $v$ darts

Comment: The formula can be found on page 13 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.11031.pdf

Comment: ok, the question is clear now. I think you can add the link in the question. I'm not sure of the answer though, I'll let someone else answer

Comment: You don’t need to add illegal moves, but you do need to include all $z$ that can result from each legal move.  Your first approach omits terms that correspond to missing the target.

Comment: If the score is 2 and a player aims at D1 and misses, the outcome leads to a bust. Hence the resulting *z* is illegal right? So these terms are omitted rightfully I believe. In this particular state (s=2), we can only consider D1 right?

Comment: Isn't that just the "otherwise" case of $f$, where $s_{i+1}=s_i$?  You must consider all possible outcomes $z$ for each action $\mu$ so that $\sum_z p(z;\mu) = 1$.

Comment: Yes it is. But in the "otherwise" case we have a circular reference right? The value function of score s depends on the probability of the "otherwise" cases multiplied by the value function of the bust cases (which is the value function itself again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each state $s$, you want to compute the value function $V(s)$, which satisfies $V(0)=0$ and the Bellman equation for $s \not= 0$:
$$V(s) = \min_\mu\left\{1+\sum_z V(f(s,z)) p(z;\mu)\right\}. \tag{13}$$
The $\min_\mu$ is over all legal actions $\mu$ in state $s$.  The $\sum_z$ is over all outcomes $z$ that can occur when action $\mu$ is taken in state $s$.  As a consequence, $\sum_z p(z;\mu)=1$ for each $\mu$, so you can use that property to help check that you have constructed $(13)$ correctly when you write everything out explicitly with actual numbers.  In particular, when $s=2$ and the only legal action is $\mu=D_1$, the Bellman equation is
$$V(2) = 1+V(0) p(D_1;D_1) + V(2) (1-p(D_1;D_1)) = 1+ V(2) (1-p(D_1;D_1)),$$
which implies that $V(2)=1/p(D_1;D_1)$.

If $f(s,z) < s$ for all $z$ such that $p(z;\mu)>0$, you can solve $(13)$ recursively by considering states in increasing order.  But as you have observed, sometimes $f(s,z)=s$ when $p(z;\mu)>0$, which leads to an equation with a circular reference in that $V(s)$ appears both on the left-hand side and on the right-hand side as a minimand.  In this situation, there are several approaches to solve $(13)$, including [value iteration, policy iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process#Algorithms), and linear programming (LP).  The LP is to maximize $\sum_s V(s)$ subject to
\begin{align}
V(s) &\le 1+\sum_z V(f(s,z)) p(z;\mu) &&\text{for $s \not= 0$ and all $\mu$} \\
V(0) &= 0 \\
V(s) &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $s$} \\
\end{align}
The positive LP dual variables indicate which action or actions to take in each state.

For an application to the casino game blackjack (where the problem is to maximize expected profit rather than minimize the expected number of darts thrown), see [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2016/06/20/computing-an-optimal-blackjack-strategy-with-sasor/).

Comment: Thank you!  It finally makes sense now. Because we want to minimize the value function, we need the denominator to be as large as possible. Hence, we aim for D1 and not D19 when targeting D1..

Comment: Thanks for help. I asked a new question regarding the same subject. Can you take a look?  (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/bellman-equation-for-darts-that-minimizes-the-number-of-turns)