# Bellman equation for darts that minimizes the number of turns

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

I want to formulate a game of darts as a dynamic program again. This question is closely related to my previous [post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6934/circular-reference-in-states-of-the-bellman-equation) where I wanted to minimize the number of throws to reach checkout.
Now the goal is to minimize the number of turns.

A turn consists of three darts. Each dart is used unless you win by checkout, or go bust in which case you revert to the score before the turn started. A state can be described as *(s, i, u)* where

- *s* is the score at the beginning of the turn
- *i* ∈ {1, 2, 3} is the number of throws remaining in the turn
- *u* is the score within the turn

In addition, we have *z* that represents the outcome of the dart throw.

```
z ∈ {Miss, S1, S2, S3, ..., D1, D2, D3, ..., T1, T2, T3, SB, DB}
```

Each *z* represents a numerical score. For example,  *h(T20) = 60*. We assume that a player can aim at sixty specified points on the dartboard. The aiming location is defined as *µ*. If *µ = D1* then the player aims at the center point of the *D1* region. However, when the player aims at *D1*, there is also a possibility that the dart ends up in the *S1*. This probability is defined as *p(S1; D1)*.
Logically, each throw results in a value for *z*. Hence,

[image]

If *i = 3*, there are three darts to be throwed. Hence *u = 0.* The state transition now satisfies (s*, i*, u*) = f((s, i, u), z) where

[image]

The Bellman equation is defined as:

[image]

With *V(0,i,u) :=0* for any *i*, *u*. A turn is counted only when the turn has been completed. This is the case when there is a checkout, bust or the third dart is thrown.
There is a monotonic structure so we can solve the recursively by considering states in increasing order like *V(2,i,u), V(3,i,u), …, V(501,i ,u)*. All of the above can be found on page 13 and 14 of the following [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346143239_Play_Like_the_Pros_Solving_the_Game_of_Darts_as_a_Dynamic_Zero-Sum_Game).

Let’s say that *s = 2*. If *s = 2*, *u* is always equal to 0, otherwise there would be a bust. Do we start with calculating *V(2,3,0)* or *V(2,1,0)*? So, do we solve the states in increasing or decreasing order of *i*?

**V(2,3,0)**
I believe there are three possibilities:

- checkout; throw *z = D1* -> *V(0,3,0)*
- miss; throw *z = miss* -> *V(2,2,0)*
- bust; throw anything other than D1 and miss -> *V(2,3,0)*

If we insert this in the Bellman equation, we get the following:

> V(2,3,0) = [1 + V(0,3,0)] p(D1;µ) + [0 + V(2,2,0)] p(miss;µ) + [1 +
> V(2,3,0)] (1 – p(D1;µ) – p(miss;µ))
>
> V(2,3,0) = p(D1;µ) +  p(miss;µ)V(2,2,0) + 1 – p(D1;µ) – p(miss;µ) +
> V(2,3,0) – p(D1;µ)V(2,3,0) – p(miss;µ)V(2,3,0)
>
> V(2,3,0) = p(miss;µ)V(2,2,0) + 1 – p(miss;µ) + V(2,3,0) –
> p(D1;µ)V(2,3,0) – p(miss;µ)V(2,3,0)

**V(2,1,0)**
If we should start with *i = 1* then the possible outcomes lead to the following states:

- checkout; throw *z = D1* -> *V(0,3,0)*
- miss; throw *z = miss* -> *V(2,3,0)*
- bust; throw anything other than D1 and miss -> *V(2,3,0)*

Inserting this, gives:

> V(2,1,0) = [1 + V(0,3,0)] p(D1;µ) + [1 + V(2,3,0)] (1 – p(D1;µ))
>
> V(2,1,0) = p(D1;µ) + 1 – p(D1;µ) + V(2,3,0) – p(D1;µ)V(2,3,0)
>
> V(2,1,0) + p(D1;µ)V(2,3,0) = 1 + V(2,3,0)

Both value functions have an unknown term. Please show me where I should start / how I save the Bellman equation for *s = 2*. Thanks

*Updated*

I calculated **V(2,2,0)**:

> V(2,2,0) = [1 + V(0,3,0)] p(D1;µ) + [0 + V(2,1,0)] p(miss;µ) + [1 +
> V(2,3,0)] (1 – p(D1;µ) – p(miss;µ))
>
> V(2,2,0) = p(D1;µ) + p(miss;µ)V(2,1,0) + 1 – p(D1;µ) – p(miss;µ) +
> V(2,3,0) – p(D1;µ)V(2,3,0) – p(miss;µ)V(2,3,0)
>
> V(2,2,0) = p(miss;µ)V(2,1,0) + 1– p(miss;µ) + V(2,3,0) –
> p(D1;µ)V(2,3,0) – p(miss;µ)V(2,3,0)

Comment: In your $V(2,3,0)$ calculation, you changed $V(2,2,0)$ to $V(2,1,0)$ in the last line. I suggest writing out the Bellman equation for $V(2,2,0)$ and seeing if that helps in solving the other two.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't see how it helps me because `V(2,2,0)`  has two unknown variables

Comment: You now have three linear equations in three variables.  If they are linearly independent, you can solve for all three variables.

Comment: Nice, how do I check if they are linear independent? They look like it right

Comment: Yes, you can solve each of the first two equations for $V(2,2,0)$ and $V(2,1,0)$ in terms of $V(2,3,0)$ and substitute into the third equation, which you can then solve for $V(2,3,0)$.